# how to use scrapy with tkinter smoothly?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to use scrapy with a GUI that i have made with tkinter and spider is working fine from alone and with GUI but when i start scrapy spider with a GUI button, the GUI is not Responding as you can see in the image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffJCp.png)

here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('300x200')
        self.button = Button(self.root,
                          text = 'Click Me',
                          command=lambda:self.pop_up())
        self.button.pack()
    self.root.mainloop()


def scrape(self):
   process = subprocess.Popen("scrapy runspider url_scraper.py -o output.csv")
   process.wait()

def pop_up(self):
    top = Toplevel()

    btn = Button(top, text="Output filename: ")
    e = Entry(top)
    scrape = Button(top, text="Start", command=lambda: [top.destroy(), self.scrape()])

    btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
    e.grid(row=1, column=1)
    scrape.grid(row=2, column=0)


app = Test()
```

I simply just want them to not hang while my scraper scrapes the data. please help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `process.wait()` will block the application.

Comment: use the threading module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process.wait()` waits for the process to complete, preventing your GUI's mainloop from running. You could remove this, or use `threading`.

```
from threading import Thread

def threaded_function(arg):
    process = subprocess.Popen("scrapy runspider url_scraper.py -o output.csv")

thread = Thread(target = threaded_function, args = (an_argument, ))
thread.start()
```

Comment: It is working but can you define this: args = (an_argument, ). how can i pass arguments and use them? my code is:

`def scrape(self, filename):
        thread = Thread(target=thread_scrape, args=(filename))
        thread.start()


        

def thread_scrape(self, filename):
        process = subprocess.Popen(f"scrapy runspider url_scraper.py -o {filename}.csv")`

but it is giving error:
TypeError: thread_scrape() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given

Comment: `args=(filename)` should be `args=(filename,)` because `args` is expected to be a tuple or list.  BTW, threading is not necessary when `subprocess.Popen()` is used.

Comment: In order to use any other argument using higher order function?